# Attachment in webservice with Flex

Tags: apache-flex, web-services, attachment

Does anybody know if it's possible to call a webservice with an attachment from Flex Webservices?
I was looking around, and it seems that you can do that in Flash Player 10... any clue? Any documentation?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the Flex SDK code is not able to work with SOAP attachments, see this [bug](http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-13381).